# No such file error when using a Java Makefile in Linux

Tags: java, linux, makefile

I need to compile a .java file with a makefile. I made a fairly simple one but when I run the generated .class file I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:947)
at BadThread.<init>(Base.java:20)
at Base.main(Base.java:13)
```

I know that Makefiles are not the best ways to run java code, but this is a requirement.

This is my makefile:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
$(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
CLASSES = \
    Base.java 
default: classes
classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
clean:
$(RM) *.class
```

The file I'm trying to compile is this one:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Base {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      new Thread(new BadThread("./output/"+i+".text")).start();
    }    
  }
}
class BadThread implements Runnable{
  public BadThread(String filePath) throws IOException{
    File f=new File(filePath);
    if(f.exists()==false){f.createNewFile();}
    dos=new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
  }
  private DataOutputStream dos;
  double val=0.0D;
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<1024000;i++){
          val=Math.random();
          for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            dos.writeDouble(val+j);
          }
        }
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){return;}
  }

}
```

Comment: Well, which file are you trying to create? This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the makefile but is a bug in your Java program.

Comment: I edited the original text

Answer (score 2):

The directory `output`, in which you're trying to create new files, doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh thanks man! I could have sworn it was something from the Makefile. Cheers!